# Socket code works in main but fails in other function

Tags: c, sockets

The first code snippet is just of main all I am doing is calling the outOfMain function

```
int main(int argc , char* argv[]) {
    outOfMain();
}
```

The second is outOfMain - The code I want to work

```
    void outOfMain() {
        printf("%s\n", "project 2 started");

        int mpSockDescriptor = mp_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_MPTCP, 0);

        struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
        serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddress.sin_port = htons(5233);
        serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("xxx.xxx.xx.xx");

        struct sockaddr* sAddr = (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress;

        int mpConn = mp_connect( mpSockDescriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        if(mpConn) {
            printf("failure to connect\n");
        }
        printf("adsf\n");

        struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
        clientAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        clientAddress.sin_port = htons(5233);
        clientAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("localhost");

        struct mptcp_header mpHeader;
        mpHeader.seq_num = 1;
        mpHeader.dest_addr = serverAddress;
        mpHeader.src_addr = clientAddress;
        mpHeader.total_bytes = sizeof("MPREQ 1");
        mpHeader.ack_num = 1;

        struct packet packing;
        packing.header = &mpHeader;
        char* sendReq = (char*) malloc(128*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(sendReq, "MPREQ 1");
        packing.data = (char*) malloc(128*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(packing.data, sendReq);
        printf("%s\n", packing.data);


        printf("%d\n", mpSockDescriptor);
        printf("%zu\n",mp_send(mpSockDescriptor, &packing, sizeof(packing), 0));
        struct packet packRecv;
        printf("adf\n");
        printf("%d\n", mpSockDescriptor);
        mp_recv(mpSockDescriptor, &packRecv, sizeof(struct packet), 0);
}
```

Then the third is the header file just to show that I am including outOfMain so the act of calling it isn't giving me the error

```
#ifndef MPTCP_H
#define MPTCP_H

// C libraries
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// MPTCP macros
#define SOCK_MPTCP 2          // socket type for mptcp connections
#define RWIN       2048       // maximum receiver window
#define MSS        128        // sender maximum segment size


/******************************************************************************
 * TCP data structures                                                        *
 ******************************************************************************/
/******************************************************************************
 * packet header holds information about the current packet + connection      *
 ******************************************************************************/
void outOfMain();

struct mptcp_header {
    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;    // remote destination address
    struct sockaddr_in src_addr;     // local sender address
    int                seq_num;      // sequence number ( first data byte )
    int                ack_num;      // ACK number ( next expected data byte )
    int                total_bytes;  // total bytes of data to transmit
};

/******************************************************************************
 * packet holds information about the data contained + connection             *
 ******************************************************************************/
struct packet {
    struct mptcp_header * header;       // pointer to packet header
    char                * data;      // segment of data
};

struct sendStruct {
    char** buff;
    int portNumber;
    struct sockaddr_in* cInfo;
};


/******************************************************************************
 * TCP wrapper functions                                                      *
 ******************************************************************************/
/******************************************************************************
 * receive UDP datagram(s) as TCP packet                                      *
 *  - returns total bytes of data received                                    *
 ******************************************************************************/
ssize_t mp_recv   ( int sockfd, struct packet * recv_pkt, size_t data_len, int flags );

/******************************************************************************
 * send UDP datagram(s) as TCP packet                                         *
 *  - returns total bytes of data sent                                        *
 ******************************************************************************/
ssize_t mp_send   ( int sockfd, const struct packet * send_pkt, size_t data_len, int flags );

/******************************************************************************
 * create connection with hostname, port                                      *
 *  - returns 0 on success                                                    *
 ******************************************************************************/
int     mp_connect( int sockfd, const struct sockaddr * addr, socklen_t addrlen );

/******************************************************************************
 * create MPTCP socket                                                        *
 *  - returns socket descriptor for new connection                            *
 ******************************************************************************/
int     mp_socket ( int domain, int type, int protocol );

/******************************************************************************
 * prints packet header information + data load                               *
 *  - returns nothing, prints to standard out                                 *
 ******************************************************************************/
void    print_pkt( const struct packet * );
void failSuccess();

#endif // MPTCP_H
```

What I am doing in order is:

1. creating a multi-thread socket
2. Connecting that socket to a specific port and server address.
3. Sending a specific string to the server
4. Waiting for a response using mp_recv

What I don't understand is that when this exact same code is inside of `main ()`, it works perfectly.  But, when it is not in `main()`, it has a segfault 11 at the `mp_recv` function call.  So I feel like the solution must have more to do with how C works and not my specific code.

Also, I need to have it outside of `main()` because I need to be able to use multi-threading.

I feel like I must be missing some elementary lesson in C right now.

Comment: There is no link. Can you put the code directly in the question ?

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of your code are absolutely useless to us. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why. Then take the [tour] and read the [help] pages, particularly [ask], and come back and [edit] your post to include all **relevant** information here, in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got lucky once, unlucky the other time. You have not initialized `struct packet packRecv;`.

Comment: Wow I knew it had to be something silly like that.  However, can you explain why it needed to be initialized.  Because let's say I only created a struct packet pointer and put that into mp_recv.  Wouldn't that then point to a struct sent by the server?

Comment: Because otherwise `packet.header` and `packet.data` are pointing anywhere into space. Where did you plan on getting the header and the data *from* after the receive? They point to memory in *your* address space, not somewhere magically provided by the peer.